# iOS messaging app animation in android listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, animation, android-listview

I have a listview and a edittext below listview. User types message in edittext and press enter and the text is shown as a row in listview.

I am trying to emulate iOS-8 messaging app animation in this app. The animation should only be shown when we are adding new message in listview. In iOS app message comes out from edittext and then attached to listview (translate animation) with a scaled and alpha animation. I am very new to android and attempted very basic version of it. My chat row is coming from bottom of listview but not coming from edittext.

Thanks in advance

**Code**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<String> values;

private boolean shouldAnimate = false;
Animation animation;

ChatAdapter(Context context, List<String> values){
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.up_from_bottom);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(values.get(position));

    //animate only the last view when getView is called through notifyDataSetChanged()
    //getView() can be called from variety of reasons but we only want to show animation when a item is added( notifyDataSetChanged)
    if(position == getCount() -1 && shouldAnimate) {
        v.startAnimation(animation);
        shouldAnimate = false;
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    shouldAnimate = true; //it is called when an item is added to listview and we want animation on last item when item is added.
}

}
```

**XML animation file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-80%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="2000%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="800" />
```

**Full code here**

https://github.com/gs-ronak/AnimationTest/tree/master/app

Comment: This is not what you would like to hear, but IMHO animating things from another OS is not only not trivial (sometimes), due to different paradigms, but also will make your app out of context and less usable for users. Trust me, I played a lot with this.

Comment: I don't want any exact animation but want similar like the text I am writing in edittext should animate from that position to list from where it is going to attach. Help me to do this part

Comment: @Umka
Also need to know how to combine translate animation with alpha animation. In this translate animation initial and final position keeps changing of different views but don't know how to calculate initial and final position for translate animation